# Selenium Webdriver pdf file signature location

Tags: java, selenium, pdf, webdriver, pdfbox

I find it more difficult to get solution for my issue.

Actually i am trying to upload a pdf into a website and i need to open the uploaded file and i need to place a x mark in the document, where another person needs to sign.

I have done with the file upload and now i need to open the uploaded pdf and mark the x mark for signature. The x mark will be placed once you click inside the opened document with your mouse cursor.

I have listed my code below,
Please let me know how to clear this issue.

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Dasenddoc {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://pp.govreports.com.au/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testDasenddoc() throws Exception {
    driver.get("https://ppaccounts.govreports.com.au/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("vignesh@eimpact.com.au");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("Viki2607");
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("vignesh2016@eimpact.com.au");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
    driver.get("https://ppda.govreports.com.au/");
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("My Documents - Digital Authenticatiion"));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("newdoc")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Send a Document")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("files")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("files")).sendKeys("E:\\Vignesh\\Manual\\Documents\\ITR sample files\\Individual_Tax_Return__03072013022155765.pdf");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[4]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Name")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Name")).sendKeys("Vignesh K S");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[5]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("vignesh@eimpact.com.au");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Message")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Message")).sendKeys("Hi Clients");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[8]/div")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("PvtMessage")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("PvtMessage")).sendKeys("Hi Viki");
    driver.findElement(By.id("saveprivatemsg")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Continue")).click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your pdfbox code?

Comment: I have not written the pdfbox code before... I don't know how to do it... Can u help me plz...

Comment: There is no information on how the site tested here works, so people cannot do more than guess. Either make the site publicly accessible or describe it sufficiently.

Comment: Download the PDFBox source code and look at the many examples. From what I understand, the problem is unrelated to selenium. You just want to write an "X" at location (X,Y).